# Not able to create the table in SQL

Tags: sql, database

The code works. It is a simple database about a supplier and their details. However, I can't create a table when inserting ''' SELECT * FROM SUPPLIER '''

```
CREATE TABLE Supplier(
ID varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
supplierName varchar(20),
phoneNumber varchar(15),
address varchar(15),
size varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Supplier(ID, supplierName, phoneNumber,address, size)
Values ('A100', 'Daryl', 'Rose-Belle Rue 99', 57615692, 'Small'),
       ('A101', 'Raquil', 'Quatre-Bornes Chemin Ferre 82', 57889958, 'Large'),
       ('A102', 'Yohan', 'Flaq Casal 76', 59864892, 'Medium'),
       ('A103', 'Hassan', 'Nitro street 69', 54863289, 'Small'),
       ('A104', 'Roger', 'Turo Rue 420', 57894256, 'Large')
;
```

At first, I was getting the error '''Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'''. So, I changed its format.

Now, it shows this error '''Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'supplierName' in 'field list''''

Comment: Your insert statement doesn't make sense, you have `ID, supplierName, phoneNumber...`, but the data looks like `id, name, address`.  Are you sure that 1) the table is defined as you presented, and 2) your phone number field is a varchar and not an integer?  (You should make phone numbers strings and not integers anyway)

Comment: If you actually try to execute what you have included in your question you will immediately see the issue, you are inserting the address into the phone number column.

Comment: You mention errors, but the posted code will give a different error, so it is unclear what problem and what code you actually have. Also, "However, I can't create a table when inserting" doesn't make any sense at all

Answer (score 2):

You should double check your insert query.

Seems you are inserting the address as the phone number and viceversa, also you defined phoneNumber as varchar (which is fine) and you are inserting it as an integer.

So instead of doing: `('A100', 'Daryl', 'Rose-Belle Rue 99', 57615692, 'Small')`

Try with: `('A100', 'Daryl', '57615692', 'Rose-Belle Rue 99', 'Small'),`